# How many MACOs were on board the Enterprise?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

How many MACOs were on board the Enterprise?

I remember an episode where Captain Archer told Major J. Hayes to bring six of your best men, so that implies there were at least more than seven on board.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Between 2151 and 2154, we observe no less than 25 [MACOs on the Enterprise](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Enterprise_(NX-01)_personnel).  The overwhelming majority of these characters serve little useful purpose in the show, other than to appear in the background in order to make everything look super serious and to get shot at during away missions.

- [Austin](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/G._Austin)
- [Azar](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/R._Azar)
- [Brown](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/V._Brown)
- [Carender](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Carender)
- [Chang](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Chang_(Corporal))
- [Cole](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amanda_Cole)
- [Forbes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M._Forbes)
- [Hamboyan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/E._Hamboyan)
- [Hawkins](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/F._Hawkins)
- [Hayes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/J._Hayes) (in Cmnd)
- [Kelly](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelly_(Corporal))
- [Kemper](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/N._Kemper)
- [McKenzie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/J._McKenzie)
- [Money](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/S._Money)
- [Moreno](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/B._Moreno)
- [Myers](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/N._Myers)
- [O'Malley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/O%27Malley)
- [Palmer](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/T._Palmer)
- [Parsons](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Parsons)
- [Richards](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/R._Richards)
- [Romero. M](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M._Romero_(Corporal)) (Cpl)
- [Romero. M](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/M._Romero_(Private)) (Pvt)
- [Ryan](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/R._Ryan)
- [Walker](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Walker_(male))
- [Willis](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/W._Woods)

Comment: they are like future red-shirts

Comment: @Himarm: It's like it has always been since TOS. Away mission in an unknown or specifically dangerous place of any kind with some bridge officers (main cast) and a small number of generic people never seen before...."They're dead, Jim!"

Comment: @Himarm - Well spotted. That's precisely the purpose they serve in the plot.

Comment: @Richard : I believe that Pvt. M Romeo is "M. Romero" too.  Apparently, the actor re-used the costume that was used for Cpl. Romero, possibly by error.  I wonder how this should be interpreted in-universe.